# Undeletable desktop.ini file

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, desktop.ini

In my C:\dev folder used for storing programming projects I see a desktop.ini file, which is visible in command prompt only and it is undeletable. What is this and how do deal with it?

Comment: So if a file is hidden and undeletable one should delete it before they know what it is or does? .ini files are configuration files, deleting it may have a negative affect.

Answer (score 1):

Download the excellent, free, [LockHUnter](https://lockhunter.com/).

In the rare event that it can't delete a file immediately, it can delete it at the next Windows restart

Answer (score 0):

I use Unlocker 1.92 for this (Majorgeeks web site). It will normally delete a file that cannot be deleted. If not, it will be deleted at the next restart (like the other tool above)